# Tracing which process that has opened a particular file

Tags: c++, winapi, file, process-management

From kernel mode in Windows I'm able to intercept and monitor virtually all actions performed on a particular disk. When a file is opened for any purpose I get an event.

Now I want to trace which application that opened it. I think this should be possible but don't know how.

I'm using the standard file management functions in Windows Win32 API.

Thanks in advance.

/Robert

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just use Win32 N.API to get the pid from the File handle.
It's a FAQ for 15 years...

Answer (score 3):

[Sysinternals Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) (free) does this, and better yet they describe how they did it:

> For the Windows 9x driver, the heart
>   of FileMon is in the virtual device
>   driver, Filevxd.vxd. It is dynamically
>   loaded, and in its initialization it
>   installs a file system filter via the
>   VxD service,
>   IFSMGR_InstallFileSystemApiHook, to
>   insert itself onto the call chain of
>   all file system requests. On Windows
>   NT the heart of FileMon is a file
>   system driver that creates and
>   attaches filter device objects to
>   target file system device objects so
>   that FileMon will see all IRPs and
>   FastIO requests directed at drives.
>   When FileMon sees an open, create or
>   close call, it updates an internal
>   hash table that serves as the mapping
>   between internal file handles and file
>   path names. Whenever it sees calls
>   that are handle based, it looks up the
>   handle in the hash table to obtain the
>   full name for display. If a
>   handle-based access references a file
>   opened before FileMon started, FileMon
>   will fail to find the mapping in its
>   hash table and will simply present the
>   handle's value instead.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternals did a so good job at doing it and explaining it, that some source code of old version are still available [here](http://www.wasm.ru/baixado.php?mode=tool&id=283) for instance, and the code is well documented (imho). It could be a good start as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "handle.exe" app from Sysinternals.

Or, are you actually trying to do this programmactically?

Comment: Yes, programmatically, hence "file management functions in win32 api" and "events"