# How do I Monitor Text File Changes with C++? Difficulty: No .NET

Tags: c++, file, monitoring

Use case: 3rd party application wants to programatically monitor a text file being generated by another program. Text file contains data you want to analyze as it's being updated.

I'm finding a lot of answers to this question wrapped around FileSystemWatcher but let's say you are writing an application for a Windows machine and can't guarantee .NET is installed.

Are there any libraries out there available for this, or am I just going to have to roll my own solution then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can monitor a directory with [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417.aspx) works on any windows.
It's efficent if you know where the file is - otherwise you can use the virtual driver/Filemon described below to check for changes anywhere on the system.

Example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution could be to check the last modified time stamp of the file.

If you use the _stat64() function to do this, it becomes a cross-platform solution.

Example code:

```
struct __stat64 fileinfo;

if(-1 != _stat64(filename, &fileinfo)
   return fileinfo.st_mtime;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that FindFirstChangeNotification will not work on single files.

Comment: Simply reading the modification time does not help to find a file change. At least you have to compare the current time with a time before modification.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this : [Tracing which process that has opened a particular file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231547/tracing-which-process-that-has-opened-a-particular-file#231585)

again  [sysinternal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) gave some tips and [tools](http://www.wasm.ru/baixado.php?mode=tool&id=283)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like what FileMon, from sysinternals (now MS) does. They do this by creating a virtual device driver that is dynamically loaded. they have a good description of how it works [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx):

> How FileMon Works
>
> For the Windows 9x driver, the heart
>   of FileMon is in the virtual device
>   driver, Filevxd.vxd. It is dynamically
>   loaded, and in its initialization it
>   installs a file system filter via the
>   VxD service,
>   IFSMGR_InstallFileSystemApiHook, to
>   insert itself onto the call chain of
>   all file system requests. On Windows
>   NT the heart of FileMon is a file
>   system driver that creates and
>   attaches filter device objects to
>   target file system device objects so
>   that FileMon will see all IRPs and
>   FastIO requests directed at drives.
>   When FileMon sees an open, create or
>   close call, it updates an internal
>   hash table that serves as the mapping
>   between internal file handles and file
>   path names. Whenever it sees calls
>   that are handle based, it looks up the
>   handle in the hash table to obtain the
>   full name for display. If a
>   handle-based access references a file
>   opened before FileMon started, FileMon
>   will fail to find the mapping in its
>   hash table and will simply present the
>   handle's value instead.