# How to enumerate all opened handles of specified process in kernel (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, kernel, handle

I have a kernel driver. How can i enumerate all opened handles of specified process in my kernel driver? I want to close these handles.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I'm assuming he wants to write code in his kernel driver to enumerate all the handles of a specified process.

Comment: @Gabe Could be, but we don't know for sure. Btw, shouldn't the driver be able to keep track of device opens, because it should receive open calls?

Comment: Dangerous. It will likely stall on pipes and mailslots.

Comment: Not to mention randomly destroying files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611885/17034

Comment: @HansPassant: It's possible that what he really wants to do is just invalidate the handle (like what happens to handles to open files on a drive after you surprise eject) rather than actually close them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to close these handles.

For what it is worth, just because something can be done, doesn't mean it should be done.  This is a bad idea.

That said, it's possible to enumerate all handles for all processes using an undocumented call to [Zw/NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with information class `SystemHandleInformation`.  A web search using these terms will yield what you want.